# I am getting "Syntax error in FROM clause"

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

I am getting

> Syntax error in FROM clause

in this SQL query trying to read an Excel file.

When I run this query in SQL Server, it's working properly:

```
OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand(
    "select policyNo ,[0] as 'Count of Deleted',[1],[3],[0]+[3] as 'Count of Transaction'
       from (select policyNo,isnull(Deleted,3) as deleted
       from [Sheet1$])t1 pivot (count(deleted) for deleted in ([0],[1],[3]))t2", objConn);
```

Comment: Don't put the whole question into the title - that should only be a quick "summary" - what are you doing? The whole question should be in the **body** of the message....

Comment: Maybe you could use [LinqToExcel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel) instead of [Read Write Excel file with OLEDB in C#](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/9014/read-write-excel-file-with-oledb-in-c-without-interop)